# value error raised from using ndb.blobproperty

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

So I'm following the Python Image tutorial for Google App Engine and I'm getting the error: "raise ValueError('Name %r cannot contain period characters' % (name,))"

I'm trying to save an image as part of my Model. I think it has to do with how I'm saving the uploaded image. I used ndb.BlobProperty() in my Model class. Here's the code.

```
class Greeting(ndb.Model):
"""A main model for representing an individual Guestbook entry."""
author = ndb.StructuredProperty(Author)
content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
avatar = ndb.BlobProperty()
date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then I tried to put the model into the database by making a model and using .put() to add. I'm not sure if the syntax is right for setting the attribute. Here's what I have in my handler class in the post(self) method.

```
greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))
greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
avatar = images.resize(self.request.get('img'), 32, 32)
greeting.avatar = ndb.BlobProperty(avatar)
greeting.put()
```

Sorry, here's the stack trace
[image]

Comment: Please edit your Q to show the whole traceback -- which will show exactly what line cause the problem **and** exactly what the problematic "name containing period" was.  Why hide info that's obviously crucial to diagnosing the problem?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that you're not retrieving the image data correctly, instead of:

```
avatar = images.resize(self.request.get('img'), 32, 32)
```

Try this:

```
avatar = images.resize(self.request.POST['img'].value, 32, 32)
```

This is [because](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#files):

> Uploaded files are available as cgi.FieldStorage (see the cgi module) instances directly in request.POST.

So this way, you can also get the filename like this:

```
self.request.POST['img'].filename
```

---

**Update:**

As [@Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916/greg) mentions, using `BlobProperty` is your immediate problem, so you need to change all this:

```
avatar = images.resize(self.request.get('img'), 32, 32)
greeting.avatar = ndb.BlobProperty(avatar)
```

For this:

```
greeting.avatar = images.resize(self.request.POST['img'].value, 32, 32)
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use BlobProperty to set the value on your model - you should just be setting the value as a string: Instead of

```
greeting.avatar = ndb.BlobProperty(avatar)
```

try:

```
greeting.avatar = avatar
```